# Is explicit primitive type casting supported?

Tags: casting, go

Is there a way to "down cast" a custom primitive type back to its original primitive? For example casting `type AwesomeType byte` to `byte` for use by a `Writer`?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply cast with the type you want:

`var a AwesomeType; b := byte(a)`

Example: http://play.golang.org/p/-Sj7zmz6zt

Comment: Go has _no_ casts. (-1)

Comment: creack Thanks. @jnml Not to sound condescending, but what is the above approach doing? Just creating a new byte "instance" using the data that was used by type AwesomeType?

Comment: See [Conversions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions). Conversions have different semantics than casts.